# Uniform Convergence of a Recursive Function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_{0}$ in $  \mathbb R $ be an increasing and continuous function. Define $f_{n}$ as

$f_{n+1}=\arctan\left(x+f_{n}(x)\right)$ for $x$ in $\mathbb R$, $n \geq 1$.

Show that $(f_{n})$ converges uniformly in each bounded interval $[a,b]$.

Solution:

I can show recursively that $(f_{n})$ is monotone and increasing in $\mathbb R$. Considering that we are in a bounded interval, is that enough to assert that this function converges uniformly?

How may I write this in a formal statement?

Thanks

Comment: Mean value theorem on $f_{n+1} - f(x) = \arctan(x+f_n(x)) - \arctan(x + f(x))$ , where $f(x)$ is the limit function, gives us an expression for $|f_{n+1} - f|$ in terms of $|f_n - f|$. Then apply what you know about $f_n$ and use the definition of unform convergence.

Comment: How do you know 0 is between $[f_{n+1}, f(x)]$, is it because as you are asumming $f(x)$ is the limit function, then the distance of that interval must be epsilon?

Comment: I don't think I follow you. Why do you need $0$ in that interval? Yes $f$ is the limit function defined by $f(x) = \arctan(x+ f(x))$.

Comment: Because when I use the Mean Value Theoream as you stated above, I need that $f'(x)=1$ to use the expression you are proposing?

Comment: I don't think that is needed. The mean value theorem says that $\arctan(A) - \arctan(B) = \frac{1}{1+C^2}(A-B)$ where $C \in (A,B)$. The term $\frac{1}{1+C^2} \leq 1$ always and if you restict to some interval you should be able to show $\frac{1}{1+C^2} \leq r < 1$ so $|\arctan(A) - \arctan(B)| < r |A-B|$. This should give you $|f_{n+1} - f| < r|f_n - f| < \ldots < r^n|f_0 - f|$. I have not done the calculation in details, but it seems it could be made to work.

Comment: Great, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$f_{n}$ is increasing for each $x\in [a,b]$, so the pointwise limit, $f$, exists.

Then $\left | f_{n+1}\left ( x \right )-f(x)) \right |= \left | \tan^{-1}\left ( x+f_{n}\left ( x \right ) \right )-\tan^{-1}\left ( x+f\left ( x \right ) \right ) \right |\leq \frac{1}{1+c^{2}}\left ( f\left ( x \right ) -f_{n}\left ( x \right )\right )$, for $c\in (x+f(x),x+f_{n}(x))$.

Now, if we restrict $x$ to $[a,b]$, then $c$ is contained in a bounded interval, so we may choose $r>0$ s.t $\frac{1}{1+c^{2}}< r< 1$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. This means that

$\left | f_{n+1} -f\right |< r\left | f_{n} -f\right |$ and therefore that $\left | f_{n+1} -f\right |<r^{n}\left | f-f_{0} \right |$.

But $\left | f(x)-f_{0}\left ( x \right ) \right |$ is bounded by some $M$, so we have finally

$\left | f_{n+1} -f\right |<r^{n}M$, so if $\epsilon >0$ is given then this is less than  $\epsilon $ as soon as $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one question, perhaps I have a theory flaw, but by which theorem gives me that if $f_{n}$ is increasing in a bounded interval then the pointwise limit exists?

Comment: $\left | f_{n} \right |\leq \frac{\pi }{2}$ so for each $x$ you have an increasing  bounded set of real numbers, $\left \{ f_{n}\left ( x \right ) \right \}_{n> 0}$ which converges by the l.u.b. property of the reals. More precisely, the l.u.b. property assures you that, for each $x$,  the set has  a least upper bound. and it is easy to show that the $f_{n}\left ( x \right )$ converge to it. Note, this implies that the limit function $f$ is also bounded, a fact we used in the proof at then end.